# Search with multiple parameter in postgresql ltree

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I planned to implement a database that using ltree as multiple level categorization. However i ran into trouble when i tried to get an entry with path x or y.

```
         new_table
+-------+--------+---------+
|  id   |  name  |   path  |
----------------------------
|   1   |    a   |   001   |
|   2   |    b   |   002   |
|   3   |    c   | 001.001 |
|   4   |    d   | 002.001 |
|   5   |    e   |   003   |
----------------------------
```

With the table stated below, i want to get an id which started with either 001 or 002. However i can't seems to get the right query for it.

expected result: `1,2,3,4`
this works: `select id from new_table where path <@ '001' or path <@ '002'`
this doesn't (results in a syntax error): `select id from ingredient where ingredient_path <@ '001|002'`

This left me confused as the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ltree.html) stated that using | (or) symbol is acceptable.

I'm very new to ltree and hoping that i can get an answer that quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
select id from new_table where path ~ '001|002.*'
```

OR won't work for `<@` operator I think, as per docs,

> ltree <@ ltree

and `|` can be used in `lquery` instead

Answer (score 2):

The symbol | (or) is acceptable in `ltxtquery` so use the `ltree @ ltxtquery` operator:

```
select id from new_table where path @ '001|002'; -- find labels 001 or 002
-- or
select id from new_table where path @ '001*|002*'; -- find labels starting with 001 or 002
```

Comment: There is a problem with those two though, when there's a '003.001' path, the '003.001' will still be included in the query result